# Mysql DataAdapter Update Method - Doesn't Save Changes

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I'm using MySQL in vb.net 
Datagridview displayed correctly and everything works properly, the problem arises when I try to update the changes in the database with the update (method)
By default the data is updated in memory "is erased students with ID =" 2 ""
But in the database is not updated, I'm reading the documentation and should work with update
**datosAlumnos.Update(ds, "alumnos")**

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
    Public Class Form1
        Dim con As New MySqlConnection
        Dim stringCon As String = "server=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=centroeducativo"
        Dim listViewAlumnos As New ListBox()

        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Try
                con.ConnectionString = stringCon
                con.Open()
                Dim datosTablas As New MySqlDataAdapter("SHOW TABLES", con)
                Dim datosAlumnos As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM alumnos ORDER BY Nombre", con)
                Dim datosAsignaturas As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM asignaturas", con)
                Dim datosMatriculas As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM matriculas", con)

                datosTablas.Fill(ds, "tablas")
                datosAlumnos.Fill(ds, "alumnos")
                datosAsignaturas.Fill(ds, "asignaturas")
                datosMatriculas.Fill(ds, "matriculas")

                con.Close()

                Dim tabla As DataTable
                tabla = ds.Tables("tablas")
                Dim fila As DataRow
                Me.ListBox1.Items.Clear()
                For Each fila In tabla.Rows

                    Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(fila.Item("Tables_in_centroeducativo"))
                Next
                Dim filaBorrada As DataRow() = ds.Tables("alumnos").Select("id=2")
                filaBorrada(0).Delete()
                datosAlumnos.Update(ds, "alumnos")
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End Sub


    Private Sub formularioTabla(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim curItem As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
        Select Case curItem
            Case "alumnos"
                FormularioAlumno()
            Case "asignaturas"
                FormularioAsignaturas()
            Case "matriculas"
                FormularioMatriculas()
            Case Else
                MsgBox("none")
        End Select
    End Sub

    Private Sub FormularioAlumno()
        Panel1.Controls.Clear()
        Dim dv As DataView = ds.Tables("alumnos").DefaultView
        con.Close()
        Dim DataGridView As New DataGridView()
        Panel1.Controls.Add(DataGridView)
        DataGridView.AutoSize = True
        DataGridView.DataSource = dv
        DataGridView.Columns("id").Visible = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If there is an error you will never know because that blank Catch just swallows them.  You'd be better off moving that to a button click at least to debug it

Comment: Where is insert/update/delete commands? or a command builder?

Comment: You might miss me something like: CommandBuilder to mysql?

Comment: in my documentation that speaks only to oledb

Comment: What provider do you use? Devart?

Comment: MySQL, but I think I found the solution, in my documentation only puts:
'Creación del objeto CommandBuilder del adaptador de datos
Dim cb As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(daClientes)
But I think the logic is, it seems to work Dim cb As MySqlCommandBuilder = New MySqlCommandBuilder(datosAlumnos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you forget to set [`InsertCommand`](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mySQL/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDataAdapter~InsertCommand.html), [`UpdateCommand`](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mySQL/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDataAdapter~UpdateCommand.html) and specially [`Deletecommand`](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mySQL/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDataAdapter~DeleteCommand.html).

To make a data adapter update data, it should have those commands. You can set those commands manually or using a [`MySqlCommandBuilder`](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlCommandBuilder.html).

```
Dim myConn As New MySqlConnection("Connection String")
Dim myDataAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter()
myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand("Select Query", myConn)
Dim myCommandBuilder As MySqlCommandBuilder = New MySqlCommandBuilder(myDataAdapter)
```

Comment: if it appears that this was, but not quite understand how it works, because it is declared only one time and not call back?

Comment: When you create a command builder using a `DataAdapter` it creates those insert/update/delete commands for the data adapter using the select statement. To make a data adapter update data, it should have those commands.

Comment: Thanks, query, as could testify at the public level "Dim As New MySqlDataAdapter datosAlumnos" to make a save button and you can access it?

Comment: Create the DataApater in a scope that you need. When you create it using `Dim da As New DataAdapter` in the body of save button, you can only use it there, but if you declate it in class level, you can use it in all methods of your form.

Comment: By the way, posting the answer as a part of your question may be confusing for future readers and also makes the post that answers the question meaningless.  I'll edit the question and remove that Solution: looking found that this lack